# Trying to make a wrapped type family into a something Functor-like

Tags: haskell

Here is a simple example where the identity Functor works well:

```
newtype R a = R a

instance Functor R where
    fmap f (R a) = R $ f a
```

but if I add an intermediate type family, things get wonky:

```
data IntT
data a :-> b

type family   Sem a         :: *
type instance Sem IntT      = Int
type instance Sem (a :-> b) = Sem a -> Sem b

newtype S a = S (Sem a)
```

and now I can't make S into a Functor.  I can easily define a new class of Functor-like things, but then I will also need a class of Applicative-like and Monad-like, and that seems like an unhappy road.  Especially as

```
smap f (S a) = S $ f a
```

actually has the type I want, namely `smap :: (Sem a -> Sem b) -> S a -> S b`.  But, of course, this is not the type of a Functor.  (Don't you just hate it when the "same" code has 2 different, incompatible types?)

I have explored [Data.Category.Functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-category/0.3.1.1/doc/html/Data-Category-Functor.html) as well as [Generics.Pointless.Functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pointless-haskell/0.0.4/doc/html/Generics-Pointless-Functors.html), but neither seemed to quite solve my problem either.  [PointlessTypeFamilies](http://code.google.com/p/pointfree/wiki/PointlessTypeFamilies) seemed to have further good ideas, and yet I am still unsure how to get something sufficiently Functor-like out of this.

It *has* dawned onto me that even though the code for `smap` is identical to that of `fmap` for `R`, what is going on is slightly different.  In a way, if I had a natural transformation from `Sem` to `S`, then somehow I ought to be able to lift that to obtain `smap`.  At that point, I figured I might as well ask here, that might save me quite a bit of trouble!

Comment: Can you define your functor more formally? 1. S is a partial type map so cannot be a functor as is. 2. IntT is not isomorphic to Int so there is  no canonical choice of a possible functor.

Comment: My real question is probably "what is smap, as it's not a functor, even though it feels/acts like one?".

Comment: `smap` can be thought of as a functor, but doesn't mean much. it's just the 'witness' of the trivial isomorphism between subcategories of types `Sem a` and `S a` (where they are defined). What's more important perhaps is that `IntT` is not isomorphic to `Int`. That changes everything.

Comment: I'm afraid there might be some confusion of terminologies between us. In which case I will try to give a more detailed answer tomorrow.

Comment: I know that `IntT` is not isomorphic to `Int` - that is on purpose.  The whole point of Sem is to be able to map `IntT` to "other things", like for example P({even, odd}) for the purposes of doing abstract interpretation.  Or I could map `IntT` to `Nat` for computing the length of programs, and so on.

Comment: Note that what I am after here is actually just that 'witness' of the trivial isomorphism.  In general, I am actually interested in the `Applicative` version, but `Functor` is as good a starting point as any.  If I use `R`, all of this is trivial.  It *ought* to be just as trivial with `S`, but it's not -- thus my question.

Comment: I first I wrote an answer trying to convince you how smap is a categorical functor but not a `Functor`.
But reading your comments, that seemd pretty useless :-( Now I'm having the same trouble as you. I'm sorry I could not help.

Comment: Here's another Functor that isn't quite right... http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/categories/1.0.4/doc/html/Control-Categorical-Functor.html

Answer (score 3):

When I encounter a situation like this I usually switch to something like:

```
data S b = forall a. S (a -> b) (Sem a)
```

which can easily be made into a law-abiding `Functor`

```
instance Functor S where
  fmap f (S g s) = S (f . g) s
```

or I turn to [`Coyoneda`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/kan-extensions/3.1/doc/html/Data-Functor-Yoneda-Contravariant.html) to package up that behavior for me.

Comment: Note that writing `Applicative` or `Monad` for this representation will probably still be a pain, if that's a goal.

Comment: You can always use the [free Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.2/doc/html/Control-Applicative-Free.html) or one of the [free monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html) encodings from my free package to capture those, but otherwise, yes, it will be a pain. ;)

Comment: In particular my Church-encoded free monad should do the trick: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free-Church.html as, unlike the classic free monad construction it doesn't require a `Functor` for the base type.

Comment: The Church-encoded free applicative/monad won't work -- you can't partially apply type families.  But I just might be able to use the basic idea and make it work via a little inlining.

Comment: Ah good point. I misread that as you using a GADT rather than a type family.